Users and Shared mailboxes within one Excel file using powershell
Hello Stack overflow community,
The past week I have been busy to make a way for my company to extract data from Azure AD and put this in a single .xslx file. But after repeatedly trying I couldnt find a common ground to make this happen.
The data I wanted to extract were users with licenses and shared mail boxes, so that out customers can see who they are still paying for.
I have used Msol mostly since it felt like the easiest way to achieve it (or im just stubborn) but the biggest problem is that I dont know or find anything that I can use to change foreach ($license in $licenses) .
With this piece of code I have gotten close but im not quite there yet. I also dont have any prior expiernce with Powershell before writing this code.
$groupOfUsers = Get-MsolUser -all | where { $_.IsLicensed -eq $True }

$o365Results = foreach ($user in $groupOfUsers) {

$licenses = $user.licenses.accountskuid
foreach ($license in $licenses) {
    [pscustomobject]@{
    Mailboxnaam = $user.Name
    Naam = $user.FirstName
    Achternaam = $user.LastName
    Alias = $user.Alias
    Database = $user.Database
    Provincie = $user.state         
    License = $license
 }
}
}
$groupOfUsers = Get-Mailbox -filter {recipienttypedetails -eq "SharedMailbox"}

$mailboxResults = foreach ($user in $groupOfUsers) 
{[pscustomobject]@{
    }
}

$combinedResults = $mailboxResults + $o365Results

$combinedResults | Export-Excel -Path C:\Temp\CombinedResults.xlsx -AutoSize -AutoFilter

I have been looking all over the internet but i cant find a place where i can compare certain pieces of code like $license.
The end result we want is a single file where we can see the shared mailboxes and every active user.
I do want to mention that the values from both outputs are different from each other. This might mean that its not even possible.
Is there a way to make an .xlsx file containing the information of both outputs?

I do not find a '?' in this post. What is your question?

Since the data is different, you are probably better off exporting each to it's own worksheet inside the workbook. You can specify -WorksheetName for each different dataset.

After Doug Maurer told me about worksheets i incorporated them into my code which immidiatly fixed my issue.
Here is my code if anyone wants to take a look!
Connect-AzureAD Connect-MsolService Connect-ExchangeOnline


$groupOfUsers = Get-MsolUser -all | where { $_.IsLicensed -eq $True }

$results = foreach ($user in $groupOfUsers) {
    $licenses = $user.licenses.accountskuid
    foreach ($license in $licenses) {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Voornaam = $user.FirstName
            Achternaam= $user.LastName
            License = $license
            Status = $user.state
        }
    } }

$results|Export-Excel -Path C:\Temp\CombinedResults.xlsx -AutoSize
-AutoFilter -WorksheetName 'Gebruikers'

$groupOfUsers = Get-Mailbox -filter {recipienttypedetails -eq "SharedMailbox"}

$results = foreach ($user in $groupOfUsers) {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        MailboxNaam = $user.Name
        Alias = $user.Alias
        Database = $user.Database
    } }

$results |Export-Excel -Path C:\Temp\CombinedResults.xlsx -AutoSize
-AutoFilter -WorksheetName 'Mailboxen'

Thanks again to Doug Maurer for setting me on the correct path!

Welcome to SO. Thank you for posting your code to benefit other users. Don't forget you can give credit and boost the reputation of other users who have helped by upvoting their comments or answers using the small up arrow. Since your issue is now resolved, you should accept your own answer to mark it as answered.
